# ASP.NET Core 5 web api duplicates file name on save

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an API written in asp.net core 5. There I have a controller that receive a IFile object. Everything is fine till I need on the end of the process to save the file on the local hard drive. There my path named *formatedPath* is correct and it contains the full path (like: ‪D:/tanulmanyiversenyek.hu/*server*/profile/8226dfa5-2743aiE2-45cfpTjG-b186yENr-167280a987aa.png).
But when the save is called I god an exception with error message:
**D:\tanulmanyiversenyek.hu\*server*\profile of the filename** ‪D:/tanulmanyiversenyek.hu/*server*/profile/8226dfa5-2743aiE2-45cfpTjG-b186yENr-167280a987aa.png

The bolder part is added somehow. I can't figure out why.

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/image/profile")]
        [ApiVersion(ApplicationSettingsConstans.ActiveVersion)]
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpResponseType.OK, Type = typeof(string))]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpResponseType.BadRequest)]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<string> UploadProfileImageAsync([FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
            ServiceResponse<string> request = await _imageUploadService.UploadProfileImageAsync(file);

            if (!request.IsSuccess)
            {
                throw new Exception(request.Message);
            }

            return request.ResultObject;
        }

public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> UploadProfileImageAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            ServiceResponse<string> response = new ServiceResponse<string>();

            try
            {
                response.ResultObject = await ImageUploadHandler.SaveProfileImageAsync(file);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.IsSuccess = false;
                response.Message = ex.Message;
                response.ResultObject = string.Empty;
            }

            return response;
        }

public static async Task<string> SaveProfileImageAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file.Length < 1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string result = string.Empty;

            string extension = file.FileName.Reverse().Split(".")[0].Reverse();
            string fileName = $"{GenerateName()}.{extension}";

            string subFolder = UploadedFileType.Profile.ToString().ToLower();

#if DEBUG
            string path = $@"{ServerPathEnviorement.Base()}\{subFolder}\{fileName}";
            result = $@"\{subFolder}\{fileName}";
#else
            string path = $@"{ServerPathEnviorement.Base()}/{subFolder}/{fileName}";
            result = $@"/{subFolder}/{fileName}";
#endif
            await SaveOnDisk(path, file, 720, 405);

            return result;
        }

private static async Task SaveOnDisk(string path, IFormFile file, int width = 1920, int height = 1080)
        {
            string formatedPath = path.Replace(@"/", @"\");

            Image image = null;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
            }

            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
            {
                byte[] data = ImageCompressor.ScaleImage(bitmap, width, height, false);

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
                    image.Save(formatedPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg); *//error thrown here*
                }
            }
```

The same error appears form Postman or from my react app.
Interesting think is if I repleace the formatedPath variable with direct path to file like: d:/tanulmanyiversenyek.hu/server/profile/167280a987aa.png it is working !

Comment: Based on your code, I tried to create a sample, but can't reproduce the problem. I suggest you could check the followings: before saving the file, try to open the related folder and check whether the file is exist or not, and try to set a break point in the save method and check whether it is executed twice or not? Besides, in your code, try to use the [File.Exists()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) to check whether the file is exist, if exist, delete the existing file(using `File.Delete()`) or rename the new file name before saving the file.

Comment: File is not created, it's not running twice.

Comment: What does `GenerateName` do, exactly? Could you share it? Secondly, if you try `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating your path manually, does it solve the problem?

Comment: GenerateName just generates some has for the file name, like 8226dfa5-2743aiE2-45cfpTjG-b186yENr-167280a987aa. I do not want to use Path.Combine, because I want my files in the specific folder.

Comment: using Path.Combine did not do the trick

Comment: It looks like, that the problem was a path. I need to pass relative path.